# How to find webelement from within context of a element using webdriver.io

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

How to find webElement from within context of a element using webdriver.io

I am trying to find element from within context of existing element. H

```
Webelement elem1 = driver.findElement(By.id("some id"));
Webelement elem2 = elem1.findElements(By.xpath("some xpath")); //some xpath or css selector within context of elem1's HTML context
```

How to achieve this using webdriver.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
elem1 = browser.element('#some id');
elemAll = elem1.elements('some xpath');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using css selectors for it and you can use it like below example.

If I am looking for an element with classname under specific div,

findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id="my-div"] .elements-class-name")

If I am looking for an element with id under specific div,

findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id="my-div"] #elements-id")